# Javascript stops working when I navigate to a new page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a user interface using html, css, and javascript.

I have an "Exit" menu item that uses onclick="window.close();" to close the user interface that works when I open any individual page but it stops working as soon as I navigate away from that page, even when I return to the home page.

I've never been good at javascript and I have no idea why this is happening and any advice on this would be helpful.

home.html, about.html, and exit.html
(only the active class changes in the list depending on the page)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul class="banner">
        <li class="bannerleft"><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="bannerright"><a href="exit.html" onclick="window.close();">Exit</a></li>
        <li class="bannerright"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using exit.html as href in a tag you can just put some default page when the user click exit or you can use something like window.history

Comment: Hello, The reason I wanted to use windows.exit() or some other function is because I'm building an application in python and using eel to make an html/js/css front end an I was hoping to put an exit option that the user could click that would close everything.  Right now the user can only exit the program by clicking the "X" on the top right of the display window (next to the minimize and resize options).  I was hoping to have something a little more polished and user friendly.